# Download progress using SFML's HTTP class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, sfml

So I'm wondering what is a good way of getting the progress of a download when using SFML's HTTP Class / using HTTP in general. The only way I've thought of being able to do it is using tons of ranged GET requests in a separate thread, but that ofc makes the download take much longer with all the requests and all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want progress information, you should either implement it yourself (not recommended) or use another library for networking.

From the documentation of [`sf::Http::sendRequest`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.2/classsf_1_1Http.php#aaf09ebfb5e00dcc82e0d494d5c6a9e2a):

> Warning: this function waits for the server's response and may not return instantly; use a thread if you don't want to block your application, or use a timeout to limit the time to wait.

In other words, it's a blocking method that return only on timeout or completion (success or error).

Maybe have a look at [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/), [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) or maybe some other libraries.